# Create dynamic textfield?

Tags: forms, 6

I have a form builder containing the following code.

```
  $form['finput']['noreff1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('No Reff1'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#default_value' => $noreff1,
  //'#required' => TRUE,
  '#autocomplete_path' =>'noreff/autocomplete',
  '#ahah' => array(
      'event'   => 'change',
      'path'    => ahah_helper_path(array('finput')),
      'wrapper' => 'finput-wrapper',
     'method' => 'replace',
         'progress' => 'throbber',
  ),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="finput-form">', '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );   

  $form['finput']['noreff2'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('No Reff2'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#default_value' => $noreff2,
  //'#required' => TRUE,
  '#autocomplete_path' =>'noreff/autocomplete',
  '#ahah' => array(
      'event'   => 'change',
      'path'    => ahah_helper_path(array('finput')),
      'wrapper' => 'finput-wrapper',
     'method' => 'replace',
         'progress' => 'throbber',
  ),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="finput-form">', '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $form['finput']['noreff3'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('No Reff3'),
  '#size' => 60,
  '#default_value' => $noreff3,
  //'#required' => TRUE,
  '#autocomplete_path' =>'noreff/autocomplete',
  '#ahah' => array(
      'event'   => 'change',
      'path'    => ahah_helper_path(array('finput')),
      'wrapper' => 'finput-wrapper',
     'method' => 'replace',
         'progress' => 'throbber',
  ),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="finput-form">', '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
```

This code shows a fixed number of form fields (noreff1, noreff2, noreff3). If I want to dynamically increase those form fields, how can I do?

Comment: **[On February 24th 2016, Drupal 6 will reach end of life and no longer be supported.](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)**

Comment: I know this, but for some reason, I still use D6 for developing. New system will be developed under D8 off course. 

So, how I can do this?

Comment: `So, how I can do this?` I started in D7, so I stay away from D6 questions.

Comment: I never got your `If I want to dynamically increase those form fields` what exactly do you mean by that? Add another field when a user clicks a button?

Comment: If your production site will be Drupal 8, a Drupal 6 solution isn't going to be very useful. A great deal of the processing on the server side will be totally different if done right on a new project.

Comment: acrosman, thanks for your concern, but what i mean is 'other group of my division' is working on d8 part.

Comment: @noSssweat: So, I just want to show one textfield for starting. If user not use that form, it doesn't show new form. But, if user input some value in that form, when user finish inputing that value (confirm by click enter button on keyboard for example), new textfield form showd up so user can fill new value, and so on..

Answer (score 0):

> So, I just want to show one textfield for starting. If user not use
>   that form, it doesn't show new form. But, if user input some value in
>   that form, when user finish inputing that value (confirm by click
>   enter button on keyboard for example), new textfield form showd up so
>   user can fill new value, and so on.. – bandungeuy

I don't think there is a Drupal way to do that, but you can always do this with jQuery.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<form>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-first-name-wrapper">

  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="edit-first-name"><br>

</div>  


<div class="form-item" id="edit-last-name-wrapper">

  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="last-name" id="edit-last-name">

</div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function ($) {

   $('#edit-last-name-wrapper').hide();

   (function Forever(){ 

     var grabs = $('#edit-first-name').val();

     if (grabs != '') { 
       $('#edit-last-name-wrapper').slideDown(1500); 
     } 
     // slides down and shows the last name field if the first name field is not empty
     else if (grabs == '') { 
     // checks if the first name field is empty  
       $('#edit-last-name').val(''); 
         // empties the last name field, since there is no first name
       $('#edit-last-name-wrapper').slideUp(1500); 
         // slides up and hides the last name field

     }

   setTimeout(Forever, 1);

   })();

})(jQuery);
```

#### [JS Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yg3r4pca/90/)