# How do I conditionally add a field?

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I'm trying to find out any example of adding new conditional field using ajax in Drupal 8 form API, but I can't find it.

This is my code.

```
$form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
    '#maxlength' => 64,
    '#size' => 64,
    '#default_value' => $name,
);

$form['floor'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Floor'),
    '#default_value' => $floor,
);

$form['flat_per_floor'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Flat Per Floor'),
    '#default_value' => $flatPerFloor,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'Drupal\bms_flat\Form\FlatForm::flatGenerate',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event' => 'change',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'progress' => array(
            'type' => 'throbber',
            'message' => "Generating..",
        ),
    ),
);

if ($form_values['floor']) {
  $form['flats'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => $this->t('Content Type'),
    '#options' => node_type_get_names(),
  );
}

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#title' => $this->t('Submit'),
    '#default_value' => $this->t($submit),
);
```

This is the callback function.

```
public function flatGenerate(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // …
}
```

How do I add a new field after filling-up my *Flat Per Floor* field?

Comment: is flat per floor an optional field? or a required field?

Comment: It will be required field. But I didn't add the required option.

Comment: then you could go with my [answer here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201372/create-dynamic-textfield?noredirect=1#answer-201494)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in Drupal 8. Please refer my suggestion bellow.

1. Please add wrapper item for the ajax call
   eg:

   ```
   $form['flat_per_floor'] = array(
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#title' => $this->t('Flat Per Floor'),
       '#default_value' => $flatPerFloor,
       '#ajax' => array(
           'callback' => 'Drupal\bms_flat\Form\FlatForm::flatGenerate',
           'effect' => 'fade',
           'event' => 'change',
           'method' => 'replace',
           'progress' => array(
               'type' => 'throbber',
               'message' => "Generating..",
           ),
           'wrapper' => 'flat-per-floor-wrapper',
       ),
   );
   ```
2. Add the wrapper container under the flat_per_floor field

   ```
    
   $form['flat_per_floor_wrapper'] =  array(
     '#type' => 'container',
     '#attributes' => ['id' => 'flat-per-floor-wrapper']
   );
   ```

   For more details please refer the example module for drupal 8 and check the ajax form
   https://www.drupal.org/project/examples